# Gitlab ci config for Cypress tests on Svelte SSR (Sapper)

Tags: gitlab-ci, cypress, sapper

New to Sapper, the SSR version of Svelte.
I try to get the tests from the basic template to run in Gitlab.

My test job in the .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
 test-job:
  stage: test
  image: cypress/base:10

  script:
    - npm install --save-dev cypress
    - npm i serve
    - serve -s build -l 3000 & yarn wait-on http://localhost:3000
    - $(npm bin)/cypress verify
    - $(npm bin)/cypress run
```

When I tried `- npm run cypress run` after `- npm install` it could not find the server. Then i tried to install serve but I still get an error:

```
$ serve -s build -l 3000 & yarn wait-on http://localhost:3000
 /bin/bash: line 96: serve: command not found
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: As you have only installed serve locally, you might need to invoke serve directly, something like `./node_modules/serve/bin/serve` (I haven't checked the path for that)

Comment: thanks @Mikkel that's seemed to resolve the first issue. I changed my scipt to: `  script:
    - npm i --save-dev cypress
    - npm i --save-dev serve
    - npm i --save-dev wait-on
    - $(npm bin)/serve -s build -l 3000 &  $(npm bin)/wait-on http://localhost:3000
    - $(npm bin)/cypress verify
    - $(npm bin)/cypress run` - now I have the server running and it's "waiting for connections", but then nothing more happens and cypress does not run. Do I now need to use a headless browser or something to make the connection ?

Comment: I managed to get the tests running by adding the run command with & to the serve commands like this: `- $(npm bin)/serve -s build -l 3000 & $(npm bin)/wait-on http://localhost:3000 & $(npm bin)/cypress run`

Comment: OK, now the test run starts but throws an error straight away tring to access the '/' route: `CypressError: cy.visit() failed trying to load:
 http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: So is the server exiting straight away?

Comment: yes, the server starts the tests run but fail because `cy.visit(/)` returns 404 not found. From looking around I can see that this seems to be an issue with cypress set-up but I haven't solved it yet

Comment: Ok, so that means that the server is running, but responding with a 404? Surely a `cy.visit('/')` shouldn't fail. Have you tried pointing a web browser to it while this is running?